# Trouble setting up nested associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, associations, polymorphic-associations, model-associations

I'm working a document management application that allows suppliers to collect documents from doctors and I'm really struggling with the associations.  I'm hoping someone can review my association structure, as I'm getting errors and not sure I'm on the right track.

Basically, a patient can have several different documents - say one for a hospital bed and one for oxygen in this case.  A supplier would have a single patient, who has several documents.  I've built seperate scaffolds so that I can roll up all the documents into a single page per patient.

```
                                :supplier
                                    |
                            has_many :patients
                                    |
                                :patients
                                    |
                            has_many :documents
                            belongs_to :supplier
                                    |
                                :documents
                    belongs_to :supplier, through: :patients
            ________________________|____________________
            |                                           |
        :oxygen                                 :hosptialbeds
belongs_to :patient, through: :documents    belongs_to :patient,through: documents
```

I'm sure I'm not making an needed association here, but I'm too new to know better...  If there's a better way to arrive at this, I would love to hear it.

Rails 4.0
Postgresql DB

Answer (score 0):

Based on this: `Basically, a patient can have several different documents - say one for a hospital bed and one for oxygen in this case. A supplier would have a single patient, who has several documents.`

In your models...

patient.rb

```
Class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :documents
  belongs_to :supplier

end
```

supplier.rb

```
Class Supplier <  ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :patient
  has_many :documents, through: :patient
end
```

document.rb

```
Class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :patient
end
```

I think these are the associations you are looking for based on your snippet above.  Check it out, let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hmm.. @jay  Yes your solution did work well.  Considering now deleting the patients scaffold all together though because the document is dependent on the patient, where all I really need is a the document itself.  Now the route is something like '/patients/:patient_id/documents/:id' - where all documents by virtue of what they are will have a patient, just not sure it's worth the leg work to make them into their own class?